# Express login redirect issue

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple login page with username and password field. If a user provides the correct username and password, he is redirected to the dashboard properly. If he provides the wrong username/password, Express renders the same page with an error message.

However, after entering incorrect username/password for the first time, if the user provides correct username/password, he is not redirected to the dashboard.

Here's the code snippet:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    models.User
        .find({
            where: {
                username: req.body.username
            }
        })
        .then(function(user) {
            if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                req.session.username = req.body.username;
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            } else {
                res.render('index', {error: true});
            }

        })

});
```

Index.jade Code:

```
block content
    .container
        h2.login Ashajo
        if error
            h5.red Incorrect username/password
        form(name="login", method="POST", action="/")
            input(type='text', placeholder='username', name='username')
            br
            input(type='password', placeholder='password', name='password')
            br
            input.button-primary(type='submit', value='Login')
```

I have a feeling the issue has to do with express-session but I haven't been able to pinpoint anything.

Comment: logic seems ok , possible for u to post index.jade code too ?

Comment: Posted but I doubt it'd be useful.